Spack Error: Additional properties are not allowed
I am trying to build lbann in a container. The lbann package is installed within the container using spack in such a way that it makes use of the openmpi package built from source within the container.
The singularity definition file looks like this:
BootStrap: docker
From: ubuntu:22.04

%post -c /bin/bash
        echo "Running post section"
        cd /
        apt-get -y update
        apt-get -y install dkms infiniband-diags libibverbs* ibacm librdmacm* \
        libmlx4* libmlx5* mstflint libibcm.* libibmad.* libibumad* opensm srptools \
        libmlx4-dev librdmacm-dev rdmacm-utils ibverbs-utils perftest vlan ibutils \
        libibverbs-dev libmlx4-1 libnl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnl-route-3-dev \
        libnl-utils
        apt-get -y install build-essential gcc g++ 
        apt-get -y install gfortran autotools-dev 
        apt-get -y install automake wget git curl
        apt-get -y install python2 python3 vim unzip
        
        # path to mlx IB libraries in Ubuntu
        echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libibverbs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /environment
        apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev

        # Install Spack
        export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
        git clone https://github.com/spack/spack.git
        cd spack
        cd ..
        export SPACK_ROOT=/spack
        . $SPACK_ROOT/share/spack/setup-env.sh

        
        cd /
        wget --no-check-certificate https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v3.1/downloads/openmpi-3.1.6.tar.gz
        gzip -d openmpi-3.1.6.tar
        tar -xf openmpi-3.1.6.tar
        cd openmpi-3.1.6
        echo $(which gcc)
        ./configure #--prefix=/usr/local CC=$(which gcc) CXX=$(which g++) F77=$(which gfortran) FC=$(which gfortran)
        make all install
        export MPI_HOME=/usr/local
        export MPI_C_COMPILER=${MPI_DIR}/bin/mpicc
        export MPI_CXX_COMPILER=${MPI_DIR}/bin/mpicxx
        export MPI_Fortran_COMPILER=${MPI_DIR}/bin/mpifort
        
        echo -e "packages:\n  openmpi:\n    paths:\n      openmpi@3.1.6: /usr/local\n    buildable: False" > $SPACK_ROOT/etc/spack/packages.yaml
        cat $SPACK_ROOT/etc/spack/packages.yaml

        # install LBANN + openmpi
        export FORCE_UNSAFE_CONFIGURE=1
        cd /
        mkdir spack_builds
        cd spack_builds
        spack compiler find
        echo -e "config:\n concretizer: clingo" > $SPACK_ROOT/etc/spack/config.yaml
        spack install lbann@develop+numpy+cuda cuda_arch=70 ^hydrogen@develop+al ^aluminum@master ^py-numpy ^openmpi@3.1.6 

When building the container openmpi is successfully built. But I encounter the following error in the subsequent step.
  openmpi:
    paths:
      openmpi@3.1.6: /usr/local
    buildable: False
==> Error: /spack/etc/spack/packages.yaml:3: Additional properties are not allowed ('paths' was unexpected)
==> Error: /spack/etc/spack/packages.yaml:3: Additional properties are not allowed ('paths' was unexpected)
FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 1

I wonder what is wrong here.

I don't know where you got that structure for packages.yaml. See the docs for the correct structure. Also are you sure you want to use the default develop branch for this instead of a release branch?

Spack also has features to easily build containers from spack environments. Even if building OpenMPI with spack is not an option for you, you can use a base image with custom OpenMPI for spack containerize.

As for the wrong format of the yaml file, I was using the container definition file straight from the package repository.  The containerize feature could also be of help as I already have an spack env with lbann on my local machine.

From which package repository? I guess it might just be outdated.

lbann repository. It must be outdated as the last commit on the definition file is 6 years ago.

Feel free to self-answer your question if you found a solution.
